# jQuery $.ajax response from post request not able to catch in success/error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am facing issue in the jQuery Implementation and not able to get the response in the  `success: function` OR  `error: function` of the jQuery, instead I can see it in browser(in Chrome) OR in IE it ask to save json file(with the response values in servlet).

Below is my configuration

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" type="text/css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"></link>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> -->
<script src="script/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var frm = $('#ABCform');
frm.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        //url: frm.attr('action'),
        url: 'controller',
        dataType: "application/json",
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (responseJson) {
            alert(' test ');
            var $select = $('#country');
            $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) { 
                $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);
            });

            /* var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

            alert(obj.value1);
            //Perform the operation to display the successmessage here
            alert('===1==SUCCESS======');

            alert('===testing Ajax===');

             var json = data.value;

             for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
             {
                 alert(json[i]);
             } */


        },
        error: function (responseJson) {
            alert('=====ERROR======');
        },
    });
});

    $(function() {
        $("#datepickerCB").datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
        $("#datepickerRefund").datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
        $("#datepickerGenerateRefund").datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    });

}); //document ready

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">     
        <article>           
            <div id="uploadCBDiv" style="display: none;">               
                <form name="ABCform"  action="controller"  method="post">                   
                    <!-- Test START -->
                    <select id="country"></select>
                    <!-- Test END -->
                    <br>
                    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
                </form>
            </div>          
        </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet method :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("\n\n--------------POST--------------");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String country = request.getParameter("countryname");
        Map<String, String> ind = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        ind.put("1", "New delhi");
        ind.put("2", "Tamil Nadu");
        ind.put("3", "Kerala");
        ind.put("4", "Andhra Pradesh");


        String json = null;
        json = new Gson().toJson(ind);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);

    }
```

One observation I could see is , I can see that the browser URL is changed.

[image]

Comment: are you sure **type: frm.attr('method')** is **type: "get"**? The dataType must be: **dataType: "json"**

Comment: @gaetanoM : I changed the **dataType** to **json** and also hardcoded the method to **get** but I still get the same reponse in the browser and I am not able to catch it in the javascript **success/err**

Comment: After checking it again , I have observed that it was actually **SUBMITing** the form and and because of which the response is not handled on the Javascript.                                                                                                                                            To handle the things , I have changed the button type and added onClick event in the page and also written common ajax plugin function which can be used to call from common/similar button calls.
   <input id="testButton" type="button" value="Upload"/>